# Java array and split method

Tags: arrays, split

Each line represents the length, width, and depth i'm having trouble to manipulate the array because I have to multiply the numbers in order to find the volume.
I already read the text file and use the split method to read each number. All I want to do in another method is manipulate the data so that I can find the volume which is basically multiplying each column numbers. 
[Data File:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDjvY.jpg)

[image]

Heres how I read and split the method:

public static void fileReader(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
 FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
         BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

```
    String currLine;
    String [] val;
    while((currLine = textReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println (currLine);
        val = currLine.split(" ");
    }
```

}

and then I have no idea how to manipulate the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question is somewhat vague / difficult to answer. Please [edit] your question and add sample input, expected output and the code you've got so far.

Comment: If you want I can link the file so that you can read what it's asking for. Im not asking for the answer I just need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the reference to the previous array in `val` is overwritten for every new line in the file because of the while loop, so you cannot access the array returned from split() for the first and second line after reading the file completely.
One can use a two dimensional double array to store the read (and parsed *(2)* ) values *(1)* and multiply the appropriate three values from that array to get the result *(3)*:

```
    String currLine = null;
    int numberOfEntries = 0;
    double[][] values = new double[3][];    // (1)
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3 && ( currLine = textReader.readLine() ) != null; i++ ) {
        String[] valuesInLine = currLine.split( " " );

        // Check whether every line contains the same number of numbers (except for first iteration)
        if ( i != 0 && numberOfEntries != valuesInLine.length ) {
            // for instance throw an exception...
        }

        numberOfEntries = valuesInLine.length;
        double[] valuesInLineParsed = new double[numberOfEntries];
        for ( int j = 0; j < numberOfEntries; j++ )
            valuesInLineParsed[j] = Double.parseDouble( valuesInLine[j] );        // (2)

        values[i] = valuesInLineParsed;
    }

    // Check whether the previous for loop counted to 3 and did not abort because of textReader.readLine() returning null
    if ( currLine != null ) {
        double[] results = new double[numberOfEntries];
        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++ )
            results[i] = values[0][i] * values[1][i] * values[2][i];        // (3)

        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( results ) );
    }
```

Which prints `[72.0, 211.25, 38.4, 24.0, 10.5]`